# Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, permutation

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/

I am trying this code ,but it is giving me empty Output  ,Can anybody resolve this issue?
When i am using System.out.prinltn(a1) to print a1 ,it is showing me non empty list ,but when adding to the a2 ,it is giving empty output

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
      
    
 List<List<Integer>> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> a2=new ArrayList<>();
        int n=nums.length;
          ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(Integer text:nums) {
         list2.add(text);
      }
       // System.out.println(list2);
        permute1(list2,a1,a2);
        
        
            return(a1);
        
    }
    
    public void permute1( ArrayList<Integer> s1,List<List<Integer>> a1,List<Integer>a2)
    {
        
        if(s1.size()==0) 
        {
        
            //base condition
            a1.add(a2);
                System.out.println(a1);
            a2.clear();
            return ;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++)
        {
            int el=s1.get(i);
            a2.add(el);
             //System.out.println("Before" + s1);
            s1.remove(i);
           // System.out.println("After"+ s1);
           
            permute1(s1,a1,a2);
            
            s1.add(i,el);
           // System.out.println("After"+ s1);
        }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know the algorithm for permutation?

Comment: Look at a pseudocode guide on [generating all permutations of an array](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/array-generate-all-permutations).